# how to add back ground color for swing components using color codes?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, setbackground, color-codes

I want to add back ground color for my JPanel in java . Instead of using Color.RED in the setBackground function , I want to use color code like #FFF380 in the function. Is it possible to use these color codes in the function.

Comment: Why do you want to use color codes?  Are these values coming from another source?

Comment: these codes il be useful for getting different brightness of color from dark color to light color.refer this link ... but these are html color codes [link](http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely simple:

```
xy.setBackground(Color.decode("#6365ff"));
```